# Is there a Calendar program out there with features that can make the "days" be linked from 5am to 5am (one day), rather than from 12am to 12am?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, calendar, ical

What if you're a person that sleeps and wakes at funky hours and wants to schedule things from 11pm-1am, for example.  In such a case, the event would be split up into two different days.  But for this weirdo, that's actually the middle of their day.  I'd like to be able to view my "day" in one go, rather than having to flip back and forth between the end of one day and the beginning of another.  Are there any calendars that allow for this kind of flexibility?

Comment: Flagging for moderator intervention to move this to the [Software Recommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for some ideas about how to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the start of a "day" to be 05:00, then it wouldn't really be a day anymore.   You're best bet may be to change your timezone to be 5 hours off.

Comment: What is "day" anyway? I don't care what the technical start of a day, is. I'm interested in scheduling my awake hours, which is what I am calling my day. The time zone change might work out. I'll need to make my own labels for the hours, though. Thanks.